# Как использовать/применять шаблон проектирования Реестр? Где хранить данные?

Tags: php, шаблоны-проектирования

В интернете полно примеров данного класса. Но нигде не пишется, а где хранить данные эти.

Ведь после перезагрузки страницы все данные, что мы сохранили в некую внутреннюю переменную - пропадут.

Эти люди что-то знают, но не говорят?

Или этот шаблон нужно каким-либо образом использовать совместно с хранилищем `memcached`?

Или хранилище `memcached` как раз и реализует данный паттерн и нужно просто его использовать?

Единственное предназначение паттерна для кэширования или как-то где-то можно его еще использовать?  Как (если, как я написал выше - после перезагрузки данные стираются)?

Comment: в памяти данные хранятся, обычно применяется для инициализации  объектов, здесь подробно расписано http://habrahabr.ru/post/183658/

Comment: @MarselArduanov Пожалуйста, постарайтесь публиковать развернутые ответы содержащие конкретный пример минимального решения, дополняя их ссылкой на источник. Ответы–ссылки (как и комментарии) не добавляют знаний в Рунет.

Answer (score 3):

Шаблон проектирования Реестр используется **не для кэширования**, а, в основном, для замены глобальных переменных, ибо глобальные переменные это не очень хорошо.

**Реестр**

```
class Registry
{

    /**
     * данные реестра   
     */
    protected static $data = array();


    /**
     * Добавляет значение в реестр
     *
     */
    public static function set($key, $value)
    {
        self::$data[$key] = $value;
    }

    /**
     * Возвращает значение из реестра по ключу
     */
    public static function get($key)
    {
    if(isset(self::$data[$key])) {
        return  self::$data[$key];
    }
    return null;
    }

    /**
     * Удаляет значение из реестра по ключу
     *
     */
    public static function removeVar($key)
    {
        if(isset(self::$data[$key])) {
            unset(self::$data[$key]);
        }
    }
}
```

Но, в отличие от глобальных переменных, благодаря использованию этого паттерна, вы можете добавить какие-нибудь дополнительные "фишки", например блокирование переменной от изменения.

**Расширям возможности**

```
/**
* Добавим массив с для идентификации залоченных переменых
*/
protected static $locked = array();

/**
* Поменяем метод set из примера выше
*/
    static public function set($key, $value) {
        if ( !self::hasLock($key) ) {
            self::$data[$key] = $value;
        } else {
            throw new Exception("переменная '$key' заблокирована для изменений");
        }
    }

/**
* напишем "обвес" для блокировки/разблокировки
*/
    static public function lock($key) {
        self::$lock[$key] = true;
    }
    static public function hasLock($key) {
        return isset(self::$lock[$key]);
    }
    static public function unlock($key) {
        if ( self::hasLock($key) ) {
          unset(self::$lock[$key]);
        }
    }
```

И если Вам нужно хранить данные из Реестра где-нибудь, то вы запросто можете записать их куда угодно.