# PHP Abstract Registry и методы __set() and __get()

Tags: php, реестр

Здравствуйте. Хочу иметь одну глобальную переменную, чтобы была возможность работать и в контроллере, и в отображении, и в модели.
Есть код:

```
 namespace CORE{
    class Registry{
        private static $data = array();
        function __set($key,$value){
            self::$data[$key] = $value;
        }
        function __get($key){
            return self::$data[$key];
        }
        function __construct(){

        }

    }
}
```

Сделав объявление в любом скрипте:

```
use CORE\Registry;
$registry = new Registry();
```

Могу использовать:

```
$registry->name = 1;
echo $registry->name;
```

Но при этом получается, что каждый раз я создаю новый объект, хоть и массив `$data` и остается неизменным. Насколько это плохо?
Думал сделать класс абстрактным, чтобы не создавать новый объект, но тогда методы __set и __get использовать не получится, и тогда придется использовать конструкции вида:

```
Registry::set($key,$val);
```

Что не очень удобно по сравнению с:

```
$date->name;
```

Какой вариант предпочтительнее? Страшно ли объявление как в первом варианте? Или как лучше поступить?

Comment: зачем вам вообще использовать обычные динамические методы вместо статических, если работа ведется именно в статическом контексте?

Comment: Сделай сеттеры и геттеры статическими, пример кода вот тут http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/483236/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8F%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%88%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%A0%D0%B5%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80-%D0%93%D0%B4%D0%B5-%D1%85%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5/491270#491270

Answer (score 1):

если вы не хотите каждый раз создавать новый объект, посмотрите в сторону паттерна Синглтон (он же одиночка). он применяется для контроля доступа к ограниченным или распределенным ресурсам. вот пример кода:

```
class ASingleton {

    private static $instance;

    public static function instance() {
         if (!self::$instance) {
             self::$instance = new static();
         }
         return self::$instance; 
    }

    private function __construct(){}

}
```

теперь в приложении будет только один экземпляр класса и получить его можно будет через статический метод instance().

Comment: Но тогда как я понимаю придется использовать в виде: Asingleton::instanse();

Comment: Но тогда как я понимаю придется использовать в виде: $data =Asingleton::instanse(); вместо new, и если объект создан, то будет передаваться? И могу также использовать $data->name. - Все работает. Я правильно понял, что это не будет плохим кодом? Если, потом эта переменная будет использоваться и в view, и в model, и в controller? Получается удобно, но правильно ли?

Comment: для создания (получения экземпляра) объекта, да. В вашем случае клинтский код будет выглядеть где-то так: `$registry = Registry::instance(); $registry->name = 'john doe'; echo $registry->name; `.

Comment: про плохой код: синглтон часто называют антипаттерном и на то есть ряд объективных причин. ирония в том, что шаблон Реестр тоже часто по схожим причинам называют антипаттерно, да и вообще реализация реестра через синглтон - обычное дело. подумайте лучше не о том, насколько это хороший или плохой код, а о том, насколько хороша в принципе идея создания по сути обертки над глобальным массивом, от деталей реализации которой в скором времени начнут зависеть многие классы абсолютно разых слоев приложения. хотите хороший код? почитайте про dependency injection.

Comment: @IgorKarpenko в чем-то с Вами можно согласиться, но DI (впрочем как и любой паттерн) не панацея, а просто один из вариантов решения архитектурной проблемы. Но, как вы правильно написали "подумай".

Comment: @S.Pronin, DI скоре концепция, чем паттерн, хотя его действительно иногда и так называют. И да, разумеется, серебряных пуль не существует, но по моему в этом никто и не сомневался)