# Composer, подключение файлов

Tags: php, composer

Привет! Если я подключил файл в автозагрузчике Composer, как передать переменную содержащуюся в этом файле в экземпляр какого-нибудь класса?

Подключаемый файл:

```
try {
    $db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=', 'root', '');
    $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    $error = $e->getMessage();
}
```

Класс в которую нужно передать переменную $db

```
$class = new ExampleClass($db);
```

ExampleClass.php

```
class ExampleClass
{

    /**
     * @var \PDO Database connection
     */
    protected $db;


    /**
     * Constructor
     *
     * Requires a PDO connection to the database where the user's credentials
     *
     * @param \PDO $db Datatbase connection
     */
    public function __construct(\PDO $db)
    {
        $this->db = $db;
        if ($this->db->getAttribute(\PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE) !== \PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION) {
            $this->db->setAttribute(\PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, \PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        }
    }
```

Comment: ничего не возникло в голове, кроме вопроса - что?

Comment: @Bookin пытаюсь избавиться от использования require_once в некоторых местах.

Comment: Это не обьясняет причем тут класс и переменная, к тому коду что вы привели

Comment: @Bookin в __constructor класса ExampleClass требуется передать подключение к базе

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/491270/186083 например.

Comment: где код ExampleClass ?

Comment: @Bookin добавил код

Comment: @Visman Спасибо! Чую это то что надо, но пока нет серьезных навыков программирования, поэтому для меня это сложновато. :)